# How to set push notifications in android/ios with vue js?

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up the firebase-cloud-messaging to display notifications to users. Using the web notification, everything works as intended.

However, I also want to send them via app, but apps don't recognize service-workers yet.

I couldn't wrap my head around it. How to use vue.js android/ios apps to receive push notifications? Should I use plugins? If yes, which plugins? Currently using quasar, Vue.js, FCM.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get push notifications to web and Android via vue cli setup for PWA, out of the box - iOS is the lone holdout on PWAs acting like PWAs on their devices. So, for iOS only, you'll need to create a developers account on Apple and pay $99/yr, plus 20% or 30% on all revenue on purchases...though there *might* be a way around that but I think that gap has been closed via recent TOS updates from Apple...for more see Netflix and WordPress issues with native apps on iOS and the fight with apple. WP being the most recent.

Pick your choice of native app building bundles, there's React native, nativescript vue, vue-native, expo and probably a few dozen more out there.

From there check the docs. Firebase has great documentation, other packages above have great documentation and they all follow a similar path since iOS has the hoops you have to jump through to get things to build.

- [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)
- [Nativescript Docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md)
- [Push Notifications on Expo](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/)