# Connection webapp and android

Tags: android, firebase, vue.js, android-studio, web-applications

I am using vue.js webapp to show pages in my android application. I want to send push notification from android end using firebase, so I want to send data from webapp to android. I don't have any idea how to make them communicate, I.e my webapp and my android app should communicate with each other.

Comment: you can use Firebase push notification also refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772430/how-to-set-push-notifications-in-android-ios-with-vue-js and

Comment: @Khal Thank you for your answer, please let me know if during running of web-app how can I send Data from web-app to native app. For example, as soon as I am logged-in in Web-view, token should be sent to native app and native app developer can use that token to hit another Api with that token.

Comment: sorry being let i have been on another PC thats why i didn't respond and please have you solved it??